# Does this error mean grpc requests can't be accepted by proxy server?

Tags: proxy, grpc, grpc-java, hoverfly

I'm trying to route my `grpc` requests to a proxy instead of the actual server for some tests. I've set the JVM properties like: `-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888` (which is where my proxy server runs - this is actually a Hoverfly proxy server). When I try to send the request, here's the error I see:

```
2021-06-22 16:23:52.935 - - WARN i.g.n.s.i.n.c.DefaultChannelPipeline grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-16 - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, host.docker.internal/127.0.0.1:8888 => usvc.dev.hostname.com:443, disconnected
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:236)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:390)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:282)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:223)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:390)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:427)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.channelInactive(NettyClientHandler.java:432)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:826)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I don't fully understand this error message - does this mean that it could not forward the request to the proxy?

Comment: Did you use TLS or mTLS in application? Looks like there try to proxy http by https.

Comment: Just TLS afaik! I'm sorry could you explain `try to proxy http by https` - I'm not sure I fully understand